# assembly language 80x86

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, access-violation

I'm was try this program but I got error message saying

> Unhandled exception at 0x00411B4A in Number1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000AFF01.

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT

INCLUDE io.h            ; header file for input/output

.STACK 4096

.DATA
array1 DWORD 0aff01h, 0bff02h, 0cff03h, 0dff04h, 0eff05h
array2 DWORD 002ff0affh, 003ff0bffh, 004ff0cffh, 005ff0dffh, 006ff0effh
array3 DWORD 5 DUP(0)             ; reserve space for 5 DWORDs
count  DWORD ?

.CODE
_MainProc PROC

    mov ecx, 5                          ; set the loop counter
    lea esi, array1                 ; load address of array1
    lea edi, array2                 ; load address of array2
    lea ebx, array3                 ; load address of array3
    call arrMix                     ; call the arrMix procedure
    mov eax, 0                      ; set a breakpoint here
    ret                             ; return from the program
_MainProc ENDP

 arrMix PROC 
    mov ecx, count                  ; initialize loop counter
    mov esi, array1                 ; load address of array1
    mov edi, array2                 ; load address of array2
    mov ebx, array3                 ; load address of array3

arrMixLoop:
    mov eax, {esi]                  ; load element from array1
    and eax, 00FF00FFh              ; keep only bits 0-7 and 16-23
    shl eax, 8                      ; shift left by 8 bits
    mov edx, [edi]                  ; load element from array2
    and edx, 0FF00FF00h             ; keep only bits 8-16 and 24-31
    shr edx, 8                      ; shift right by 8 bits
    or eax, edx                     ; combine the two bit sets
    mov [ebx], eax                  ; store the result in array3
    add esi, 4                      ; move to the next element in array1
    add edi, 4                      ; move to the next element in array2
    add ebx, 4                      ; move to the next element in array3
    loop arrMixLoop                 ; repeat until loop counter is zero

    ret                             ; return from the procedure

arrMix ENDP
END                               ; end of source code
```

Comment: Which instruction is at `0xC0000005`?  What values were in registers when it faulted?  When you single-stepped, did anything weird happen before getting to that point?  https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/  What is the program *supposed* to do?  Also, pick a more descriptive title, like what your question is specifically about, not just the ISA; that's not going to help anyone with the same problem find your question.

Comment: Aside: why are you setting the parameter register both before calling and then inside `arrMix`?

Comment: Note that your `_MainProc` does not follow Windows register conventions, so it is very likely to cause problems in the caller function as well.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError This is masm (not nasm), so `mov esi, array1` loads the first element of the array, not it's address.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Fair enough, but still the code inside the function just overwrites the values loaded before the call, no?

Comment: @Peter, FYI, C0000005 is an error code, not an address.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> arrMix PROC 
>    mov ecx, count                  ; initialize loop counter
>    mov esi, array1                 ; load address of array1
>    mov edi, array2                 ; load address of array2
>    mov ebx, array3
> ```

You are calling the *arrMix* procedure with inputs already in EBX, ECX, ESI, and EDI. However the *arrMix* procedure begins with destroying these.

The ECX=5 setting get thrashed by loading ECX from an **uninitialized** *count* variable, and the 3 pointers get overwritten by their respective first array elements.
Because ECX very probably gets overwritten with 0, the `loop arrMixLoop` instruction starts executing its 4 billion iterations! And because the pointers are now invalid, a read/write access violation is bound to happen.

In MASM, `mov esi, array1` load a value from memory, whereas `mov esi, OFFSET array1` loads the address of the array (like you were expecting).

The line `mov eax, {esi]` has a typo on the opening square bracket. This hould be `mov eax, [esi]`.